# Listview in toolbar with android studio

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-tablelayout

I am beginner in android, and I want to integrate  listview in toolbar with android studio. Is that possible? and how can I do it ?

Comment: did you try my answer??

Comment: yes bro thnx ..but know i have another problem

Comment: in phpmyadmin config  the Maximum number of rows to display is 500 ..i cant change ir to 1000 with $cfg['MaxRows'] = 1000;

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.HeaderBar.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar_spinner_item_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/spinner_triangle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar_spinner_item_dropdown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
private class YourObjectSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<YourObject> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public void clear() {
        mItems.clear();
    }

    public void addItem(YourObject yourObject) {
        mItems.add(yourObject);
    }

    public void addItems(List<YourObject> yourObjectList) {
        mItems.addAll(yourObjectList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null || !view.getTag().toString().equals("DROPDOWN")) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_spinner_item_dropdown, parent, false);
            view.setTag("DROPDOWN");
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(getTitle(position));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null || !view.getTag().toString().equals("NON_DROPDOWN")) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.
                    toolbar_spinner_item_actionbar, parent, false);
            view.setTag("NON_DROPDOWN");
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(getTitle(position));
        return view;
    }

    private String getTitle(int position) {
        return position >= 0 && position < mItems.size() ? mItems.get(position).title : "";
    }
}
```

For more see [this](https://dabx.io/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/)